# Is the linear map $\psi: ℂ_2 \to ℂ^2, a+bx+cx^2 \mapsto (a+ib,b-a)$ bijective?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the linear map $\psi: ℂ_2 \to ℂ^2, a+bx+cx^2 \mapsto (a+ib,b-a)$

Injective?

Surjective?

Bijective?

I know the definitions of these, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: I have made a mistake, you're correct. The question should read as the edit. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: See my undeleted way. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this map is a linear map, its kernel indeed is full of $$cx^2\in\mathbb C_2,~~c\in\mathbb C$$ so it doesn't satisfy the injection property. What about being onto? Let $(\alpha,\beta)\in\mathbb C^2$. If $\psi$ is an onto map so we should have an element $f=a+bx+cx^2\in\mathbb C_2$ such that $\psi(f)=(\alpha,\beta)$. So we should have $$(a+bi,a-b)=(\alpha,\beta)$$ But what happens if $\beta$ is purely free of real part?

Answer (score 1):

Actually writing down what it is you need to prove is *almost always* a good place to start.

It may or may not be worth first thinking about the problem

> What can you say in general about $\mathbb{C}_2$? $\mathbb{C}^2$? Linear maps $\mathbb{C}_2 \to \mathbb{C}^2$?

Sometimes, the problem people have is that they focus on the details, and forget about everything else, so it helps to think about what you can say with the details removed.

Comment: $ℂ_2$ has elements that are polynomials over $ℂ$, with highest degree $2$. $ℂ^2$ has two elements over $ℂ$. I don't know what I can say in general about Linear maps $ℂ_2 \mapsto ℂ^2$.

Comment: @MrCroutini, what are the dimensions of the two spaces? What is the image of the natural basis of the first space under $\psi$?

Comment: $ℂ_2$ has dimension $2$. $ℂ^2$ has dimension $3$. The natural basis of $ℂ_2$ is $(1,i)$. I'm not sure what the image would be...

Comment: I think the natural basis of $\mathbb C_2$ is $\{1, x, x^2\}$, and of $\mathbb C^2$ is $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$..